# How to send requests over ssl?

Tags: java, ssl, jaxb, httpclient, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send a request from localhost to a server but it returns following error.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;


public class Test {

 public void connectMyServer(){

        Login auth = new Login("username", "password");

        JAXBContext cntx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Login.class);
        Marshaller m = cntx.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.server.com/requests");
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
            m.marshal(auth, os);
            m.marshal(auth, System.out);

            os.flush();
            con.getResponseCode();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            con.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try the HttpsURLConnection instead of HttpURLConnection

Comment: @smeaggie I changed it to https but still runs into same error

Comment: I'm with Jim on this; the server is not sending HTTPS then.

Comment: @smeaggie when I change the address to http and send a http request it shows error 403

Comment: @smeaggie please have a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190364/how-to-bypass-certificateexception-by-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use `HttpURLConnection` for SSL when you should be using `HttpsURLConnection`.

Edit:

I tried this:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        Map<String,List<String>> fields = con.getHeaderFields();
        con.disconnect();
    }
}
```

It runs with no problem.

Your error message indicates the remote server is responding as if it speaks HTTP, not HTTPS, regardless of what your tech team says.

Comment: Is the remote server redirecting to HTTP?  Have you looked at the traffic with Wireshark to see what's being sent and received?

Comment: Server tech team adviced me to send all connections to https, so I supose they will not redirect it to http

Comment: I changed it to https but it is showing the same error, does that mean they do not speak https?

Comment: when I change the address to http and send a http request it shows error 403

Comment: 403 is FORBIDDEN, meaning you didn't provide the correct authentication.  This means it's _definitely_ not HTTPS.  You really need to capture the network traffic with Wireshark so you can show your tech people what's happening.

Comment: please have a look at my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190364/how-to-bypass-certificateexception-by-java